# Lifecycle Management Policy for Azure Data Lake Gen 2 does NOT remove folders?

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2

I got some files stored in an Azure Data Lake Gen 2 storage account. I've set a lifecycle policy so that files are deleted after 2 days. The files are successfully deleted after said period, but of course, the folders aren't deleted, even when the folder ends up empty.

Is there some way to instruct the policy to delete the folder once it ends up empty? The problem is that I'm ending up with a lot of orphaned folders after the deletion takes place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#rule-actions)

> When applied to an account with a hierarchical namespace enabled, a delete action removes empty directories. If the directory isn't empty, then the delete action removes objects that meet the policy conditions within the first lifecycle policy execution cycle. If that action results in an empty directory that also meets the policy conditions, then that directory will be removed within the next execution cycle, and so on.

**Empty directories are deleted within the next execution cycle.**